# Cross-browser font height

Tags: html, css, font-size

As you see the `outline` is collapsed in the following sample:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  output.value = input.value;
});
```

```css
output {
  display: block;
  font: 20px Arial;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input id="input">
<output id="output"></output>
```

How can I prevent it? Do I need to give the `output` a fixed `height`? If so, what value should I give to the `height` if I want it to be just as high as the text height — not an arbitrary number? Is there a cross-browser solution?

Comment: What do you mean by cross browser? Do you get different results in different browsers?

Comment: @MrLister: Yes, the `output` height is 23px in Chrome, but 24px in Firefox, for example.

Comment: It is possible that the browsers round the line height differently. The solution for that would be to specify the line height explicitly, e.g. `font: 20px/24px 'Arial';` (This has nothing to do with the height collapsing to 0, by the way.)

Comment: @MrLister: _"This has nothing to do with the height collapsing to 0, by the way."_ Is it a good idea to use `font: 20px/24px 'Arial';` and then `height: 24px`, or do you prefer the CSS content property?

Comment: Both have advantages and disadvantages. In my solution, if you put a space in the input, the output is no longer "empty" according to CSS, but it still is according to HTML, so it collapses again. But forcing the height to 24px causes overflow if the content is larger than one line.

Comment: Wait, you can set the min-height of course. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @MrLister: _"forcing the height to 24px causes overflow if the content is larger than one line."_ I wonder how the content in my example can be larger than one line if I use `font: 20px/24px 'Arial'; height:24px;`.

Comment: The input doesn't have a length restriction, so you can type a lot of content in it. With `height` instead of `min-height`, the output will then look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VxvG.png).

Comment: @MrLister: _"In my solution, if you put a space in the input, the output is no longer "empty" according to CSS, but it still is according to HTML, so it collapses again."_ I like this approach much better than your second solution. The problem you mentioned can be avoided by removing the empty selector: `output:after {content: "\00A0";}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that elements without content collapse to a zero height. This is in accordance with the CSS specification. Fortunately, there is also a nice CSS solution for this problem.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  output.value = input.value;
});
```

```css
output {
  display: block;
  font: 20px 'Arial';
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

output:empty::after {    /* when the output is empty, */
  content:'\00A0';       /* add some content to make sure it's not */
}
```

```html
<input id="input">
<output id="output"></output>
```

Another solution is if you set the line-height explicitly, then you'll know the (minimum) height it needs to be, so you can set the `min-height` property.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  output.value = input.value;
});
```

```css
output {
  display: block;
  font: 20px/24px 'Arial';      /* added line height */
  min-height: 24px;             /* set minimum height explicitly */
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input id="input">
<output id="output"></output>
```